# Webpack not initializing javascript or including fonts

Tags: webpack, materialize

I have webpack setup and building without error.  Materializes css is being included correctly, but the JavaScript is never initialized and the fonts aren't added correctly.

I have some experience using other module loaders like require.js, but I am missing something.

These are the relevant files.  The output directory does contain all the font files renamed with what appears to be completely random.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./web/static/js/app.js"],
  output: {
    path: "./priv/static/",
    filename: "app.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
    },{
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ["style", "css"]
    },{
      test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
    },{
      test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      loader: "file-loader"
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      "./web/static/js",
      "./web/static/style"
    ],
    moduleDirectories: [
      "node_modules",
      "bower_components"
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
      "Hammer": "hammerjs/hammer"
    }),
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
      new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
    )
  ]
}
```

**app.js**

```
require('materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css');

var jquery = require('exports?jQuery!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
var materialize = require('imports?jquery!materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js');
```

thanks in advance for your help